# How does C# run inside a Razor view without compilation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, compilation

I couldn't seem to find an answer to this on the web.

Since C# is a compiled language, how is code inside a Razor view able to execute without the developer having to build again?

For example, if I load a page with this code: `@{string test = "123";}`.

But then change the code to this: `@{string test = "test";}`

How do I not need to rebuild? Also, is the thing that is allowing this to happen a C# feature or an MVC feature?

Comment: Razor files are compiled at run-time when a view is invoked (they are cached, but the cache is cleared if the view changes) - the `.cs` file is stored in your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The razor engine basically "compiles" the view.
Something like this...

```
@model Person
<html>
  <p>
  @Model.FirstName
  </p>
</html>
```

is actually compiled into a method in a class. I can't remember the exact functions it calls but it would look something along the lines of this:

```
class RazorPage<T>
{
    T Model;

    void Page
    {
        Write("<html>");
        Write("  <p>");
        Write(Model.FirstName);
        Write("  </p>");
        Write("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why no rebuild?

Comment: If a Razor file is edited on the server, MVC detects the change, rebuilds that file only, then carries on as if nothing had happened. It's a very convenient system.