# What does @model exactly do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Whenever I put `@model [Type]` on top of my Razor pages, some of the generic types and methods have their type parameters resolve to [Type], for example:

```
string DisplayNameFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression);
```

becomes

```
string DisplayNameFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<[Type], TResult>> expression);
```

How does ASP.NET Core achieve that? How does the `TModel` type parameter becomes [Type]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190342/11683. And `DisplayNameFor` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the resulting `class<Type>`.

Comment: Razor files are compiled dynamically when the app starts (or is compiled). So when you do `@model TModel` in your razor page, a .NET class in the background will generated, containing the logic to generate the Razor view. Extension Method just use the type based on what its complied to, since its generic

Comment: @Tseng how does Extension Method infer the type?

Comment: Because the types on the extensions methods are [generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics) and are infered from the object its called on

Comment: DisplayNameFor is not an extension methode.

Answer (score 5):

#### @model

The `@model` directive specifies the type of the model passed to a view:

```
@model TypeNameOfModel
```

In an ASP.NET Core MVC app created with individual user accounts, the *Views/Account/Login.cshtml* view contains the following model declaration:

```
@model LoginViewModel
```

The class generated inherits from `RazorPage<dynamic>`:

```cs
public class _Views_Account_Login_cshtml : RazorPage<LoginViewModel>
```

Razor exposes a `Model` property for accessing the model passed to the view:

```
<div>The Login Email: @Model.Email</div>
```

The `@model` directive specifies the type of this property. The directive specifies the `T` in `RazorPage<T>` that the generated class that the view derives from. If the `@model` directive isn't specified, the `Model` property is of type `dynamic`. The value of the model is passed from the controller to the view. For more information, see [Strongly typed models and the @model keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#strongly-typed-models-and-the--keyword).

Reference: [@model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#section-2)

Comment: There is a missing note, that this answer is strictly the cite from the mentioned reference link. As I know, this is the proper way to produce answers in SO in that case: citation should be strongly expressed.